# IE9 Javascript XMLHttpRequest responseXML childNodes Invalid number of parameters

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I am writing a page that uses javascript to load an xml file from the server, and then I parse it.  My code runs correctly in Firefox, Chrome, and IE10, but in IE9 the childNodes array of the responseXML object has only 1 item that says "Invalid number of parameters".  I know the xml loads correctly because the firstChild property has the correct name and value, and its firstChild property does also, etc.

I could rewrite my parsing code to work with this, but I dont really want to do that for a number of reasons.

Does anyone have any ideas what my problem is here?  I also noticed that the dataType and doctype properties of the responseXML object are null.

I checked the http header the server is sending back when the xml file is requested, and it has Content-Type: text/xml.

This is my code that is causing the problem,

```
var xmlReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlReq.addEventListener("load", onXmlReqComplete, false);
    xmlReq.addEventListener("error", onXmlReqError, false);
    xmlReq.addEventListener("abort", onXmlReqAbort, false);
    xmlReq.open("get", "tree.xml", true);
    xmlReq.send();


 function onXmlReqComplete(e){
            var xmlResp = this.responseXML;

            //this is the line that causes the error, 
            //SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'childNodes' of undefined or null reference 
            var items = xmlResp.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes;

            for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){

                if(items[i].nodeName == "#text"){
                    continue;
                }

                treeData.push(items[i]);

            }

            layoutDisplay();

        }
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Could you please post the `xmlReq.responseText`? You're textual description of the responseXML is not that easy to understand as markup…

Comment: Yeah no problem, how do I get it in a textual form that I can paste here?  I can see everything in the debugger but I dont know how to copy and paste it

Comment: Just get to the Network panel and copy the plaintext server response. Or did you mean to post the `.responseXML` document object? That would be nice as well, but I think there's no better way than selecting the debugger output. | Oh wait, you're on IE9 - then I have no idea about its devtools.

Comment: I can post the server response, but it is just xml with an http header.  The responseXML DOM object is the only thing that would be of much help

Comment: Maybe that already would help to identify what IE is stumbling upon? Have a try.

Comment: Here is the header returned, I cant seem to get the returned xml to paste into the SO question, Im guessing it is being interpreted as html and messing with a parser somewhere   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml
Last-Modified: Tue, 04 Jun 2013 19:35:24 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "5493e8a85a61ce1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 04 Jun 2013 20:02:26 GMT
Content-Length: 2218